How to change highlighted background color
When I use CtrlShift. shortcut to open up the breadcrumb view and move through various methods inside a file, each method gets highlighted. I was wondering how I can change this highlight color (in the image below, the rectangular transparent color around the replyConsumer method between line number 60 to 50).
I know it's not either of these two options:  editor.selectionBackground or editor.selectionHighlightBackground


This question is similar to: How can I change the background highlight color associated with searching (find) for a color theme in VS Code?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

or How can I change the color of the top bar that holds tabs and other actions and the breadcrumb bar in VS Code?

@Luuk Unfortunately, none of the options metioned in those questions change the color of highlighted section of code. In the above image, I want to change the transparent color of the rectangular area around the replyConsumer method.

Try: "workbench.colorCustomizations": { "breadcrumbPicker.background": "#ff0000" , "list.focusBackground": "#0000ff"} to turn the background of the pop-up into red, and the selected line to blue  for this offtopic question.  (P.S. That is " the rectangular area around the replyConsumer method"!)  (see: https://i.sstatic.net/MkZzB4pB.png )

@Luuk Sorry, my bad. I meant the rectangular area from line 60 to 50 in the above image.

I finally found it. It's editor.rangeHighlightBackground that I had to change. Thanks for the help. Here's the full list of theme color options: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors

I finally found it. It's editor.rangeHighlightBackground that I had to modify to change the highlighted section of code. Note that it should be set to a transparent color (ex "editor.rangeHighlightBackground":"#384d5d46") so that it will not block the code. By the way, here's the full list of theme color options that one can customize in vs code:
code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors
